# Trying to execute and compile C programs in notepad++

Tags: c, notepad++

I referred this article to setup compiler and execution tool.

http://codingfox.com/1-9-how-to-configure-gcc-in-notepad-for-c11/

The problem I am facing is that when I try to compile the program I have made, compiler shows up for milliseconds and disappears.Thus, I am not able to see what's wrong in that program. I want compiler to stop by and wait for my response.

Code is as follows

header files used are stdio.h and conio.h

```
int main()
{
  printf("Hello World");
  return 0;
  getch();
}
```

In case, there are more ways of what I am trying to do, please let me know.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: It probably not the compiler but your program which is buggy. Your issue is windows specific, on Linux you won't have it.

Comment: Why don't you install VisualStudio?

Comment: Just put `getch()` at the end of the program.

Comment: `compile` or `run`? ctrl+ F9 or ctrl+F5, which one?

Comment: @Basile It's just "Hello World" program.

Comment: @Igor I have used getch() in that program.

Comment: Is better if you post your code.

Comment: @Sourav When I try to compile (ctrl+F9) the program, this is when I am facing the discussed problem.

Comment: And how're you becoming sure there __is__ something `wrong in that program`?

Comment: I intentionally made errors to check whether compiler is working fine or not.

Comment: "header files used are stdio.h and conio.h" -- is that literally in your source and copied from your code? If not, **post exactly what you are using**. Why why why won't you just *do* that?

Comment: Am I correct in stating that the problem you have is that the **compiler window** closes before you get to see the output?   Everyone seems to be trying to fix your code, and I don't think that's the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Notepad++ is not an IDE. The linked article is totally lame. Either use and IDE, or open a console and use command-line tools.

Answer (score 2):

Post your code. This is need to understand if it closes because of the progam is ended, or if compiler stops on errors. In any case the article gives you instruiction to run your code, but you can also compile it, as @Sourav suggested you. If the program simply ends, as @Igor wrote, you can add a `getch()` before the end of main and the execution stops and wait for an input.

Another way is to launch the compiled program into cmd shell: it will not close the shell at the end of the program.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your output window disappears before you ever get a chance to look at it.

You took it a bit too literally to use `getch` at the end of your program.

We mean, *"at the end of the program, before the return statement"*

**What you wrote**

```
int main()
{
  printf("Hello World");  // This does exactly what you expect
  return 0;               // Your program ends here.
  getch();                // This line is NEVER run.
}
```

**What you *should* write**

```
int main()
{
  printf("Hello World");  // This does exactly what you expect
  getch();                // Pause the program for input.
  return 0;               // Your program ends here.
}
```